# javascript - loop through a table and check the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Background Information**

I have two tables, one that is a list of available users, called "users" and the other one called "selected_users".  When a row from the users table is clicked on, the app add / removes record from the selected_users table

```
<table id=users>
<tr class="odd" role="row" id="row_89"><td>89</td><td>John Doe</td><td>23819</td><td>mm2@yahoo.com</td></tr>
<tr class="even" role="row" id="row_90"><td>90</td><td>John Doe</td><td>23819</td><td>36338</td></tr>
<tr class="odd" role="row" id="row_91"><td>91</td><td>Jane Doe</td><td>23820</td><td>jane@yahoo.com</td></tr>
<tr class="even" role="row" id="row_92"><td>92</td><td>Jane Doe</td><td>23820</td><td>28519</td></tr>
<tr class="odd" role="row" id="row_93"><td>93</td><td>Jim Bob</td><td>23801</td><td>jbob@yahoo.com</td></tr>
</table>

<table id=selected_users class="table table-condensed table-bordered" width="80%">
      <tr class="info"><td colspan="4"><b>Selected Users:</b></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Question**

I need to change the existing logic so that when a row in the available users list is selected, all other rows in the available users table that has a matching "pid" (which is the 3rd column) should be added to the selected_users table.

This is the code that is triggered when someone clicks on the available users table:

```
    $('#users tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var tr;
        tr=$('<tr/>');

        var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
        if ( index === -1 ) {
            selected.push( id ); //select/highlight in list of available users.

            // Find td's inside this tr and add to selected_users table
            var tds = $(this).find('td');
            tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(0).text() + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(1).text() + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(2).text() + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(3).text() + "</td>");
            tr. attr('id', id.substring(4));
            $('#selected_users').append(tr);

            //loop through the avail users table and select all records with the same p number.
            $("users td").each(function(i,o){
                // new code goes here
            }
        } else {
            selected.splice( index, 1 ); //deselect from list of avail users
            //remove matching record from selected_users table.
            var record_id = id.substring(4);
            var rowtodelete = document.getElementById(record_id);
            rowtodelete.parentNode.removeChild(rowtodelete);
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );
} );
```

**What I have so far**

I'm thinking of adding code like this (pseudo code) in the section with the comment "new code goes here"

```
       //loop through the avail users table and select all records with the same pager number.
        $("users tr").each(function(){
            $(this).find('td ....
        });
```

I'm not sure how to do a find to see if the third column matches what I have in tds.eq(2).text()

Any suggestions would be appreciated

**EDIT 1**

This is what I have so far:

```
        //2015.06.11 - find and add all other rows with matching p number
            var thisTR = $(this);
            console.log(thisTR);
            //select all siblings with same value in third column
            thisTR.siblings().filter(function() {
                    console.log($('td',this).eq(2).text() );
                    //console.log($('td', thisTR).eq(2).text());
                    if ($('td',this).eq(2).text() == $('td', thisTR).eq(2).text() ) {
                            console.log("i found a match");
                            console.log("what is the row for: " + $('td',this).eq(2).text());
                    };
            });
```

I just need a way identify the row where the matching td was found, and then do something similar to what I'm already doing to add a row to selected_users: 
                var tr;
                tr = "";
                ... find the row and then...
                tr.append("" + tds.eq(0).text() + "");
                tr.append("" + tds.eq(1).text() + "");
                tr.append("" + tds.eq(2).text() + "");
                tr.append("" + tds.eq(3).text() + "");
                tr. attr('id', id.substring(4));
                $('#selected_users').append(tr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can use - [`.filter( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
//save a reference of the current row
var thisTR = $(this);

//select all siblings with same value in third row
thisTR.siblings().filter(function() {
    return $('td',this).eq(2).text() == $('td', thisTR).eq(2).text();
})

//Iterate through them and do what needs to be done.
.each(function() {
    //do something
    //here 'this' refers to tr (matched row)
    //$('td', this) should give you all the tds in 'this' row 
});
```

Comment: @PeterAK, please see my EDIT 1

Comment: Unfortunately, the filter function needs to return `true` or `false`, so the alert is not doing it any justice :(  **And**, I've also realized that there's a typo in  my code which I'll fix shortly ... change `=` to `==` in the `return` statement. Fixing the typo should clear the error.

Comment: the thing is, once I've found a matching cell, I need to be able to identify the row that cell belongs to i can copy the data from that row to the other table.

Comment: Do you want to copy the entire row? Perhaps you would assign the matching rows to a variable, clone them and append them to the other table.

Comment: If you take a look at my code, right before the new code, you'll see some logic where I create a <tr> and append a bunch of <td>'s to it and then add that to the selected_users table.  I plan on doing something similar with the other rows that have the same pid.

Comment: The problem I have with your code example is that once I found a match, how do I get all the td's from the matching row using your example?  Could I change your "return" statement to an "if" and then in the true path, somehow grab the rest of the <td> values ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80419/discussion-between-dot-and-peterka).

Comment: I figured out the rest.  I'm not using the .each() but thanks for the filter.  that was the key I needed.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Just in case you need any further pointers ... take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/gL7ayj1a/1/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to add the user ID to the  elements using a `data-` custom attribute so you can easily access them with a selector.

For example, notice the `data-uid` attribute below:

```
<tr class="odd" role="row" id="row_89" data-uid="23819"><td>89</td><td>John Doe</td><td>23819</td><td>mm2@yahoo.com</td></tr>
```

With that in place, grabbing all the relevant rows is easy:

```
rows = $('#users tr[data-uid=' + uid + ']');
// ...
```

Comment: I like this solution. It's very clean.  But the problem is that I'm using jquery dataTables and I don't think I can specify a custom attribute.

Comment: @dot You should be able to do it.  Please see https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ids.html